# Crash in NSDateComponents weekOfYear

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents, week-number

I'm trying to get the number of the week of the year out of an `NSDate` with this code:

```
int which = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSQuarterCalendarUnit;
NSDate* date= [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents* comps= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:which fromDate:date];

today.weekNumber= comps.weekOfYear;
```

However, for some reason it is crashing and stating:

`reason: -[NSDateComponents weekOfYear]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

The other components work just fine when I uncomment the weeknumber part:

```
int which = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSQuarterCalendarUnit;
NSDate* date= [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents* comps= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:which fromDate:date];

//   today.weekNumber= comps.weekOfYear;
today.month= comps.month;
today.year= comps.year;
today.quarter= comps.quarter;
today.hour= comps.hour;
today.minute= comps.minute;
today.second= comps.second;
```

According to the docs, `NSDateComponents` should have a property called `weekOfYear`, shouldn't it?

I'm confused, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-weekOfYear` method is available in `NSDateComponents` starting iOS 5.0 and so if you're trying to use that method on earlier OS versions that will result in the crash.

Comment: D'oh! I wasn't aware of this. Is there another way of getting the weekOfYear when I'm on iOS 4?

Comment: Check "week" property - may be it will be sufficient for you. You can also try to play with NSDateFormatter to get that value as a string and then convert it to a number (e.g. see discussion here http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10100-getting-week-number-objective-c.html)